# Error Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

project.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.pro.getAll().subscribe(
      respose => {
        console.log(respose);
        this.projects = respose;
      },
      () => console.log('error')
    );
  }
```

projectservice.ts

```
getAll():Observable<Project[]>{
        return this.http.get<Project[]>(this.link);
 }
```

project.component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let p of projects">
    <li>{{p.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

by console 
ERROR Error: "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"
    Angular 7
    View_ProjectComponent_0 ProjectComponent.html:47
    Angular 23
    RxJS 5
    Angular 9

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` give you? Is it an array? Make sure it is an array before assigning it to `this.projects`;

Comment: console.log(response):{…}
​data: Array [ {…} ]
​pageNumber: 0
​totalOfElements: 1
​totalPages: 1
​<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: Isn't response an object of objects instead of an array?

Comment: try `console.dir(response)`. Read about the difference [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log-2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show what is in the projects variable after the response?

Also, if your HTML is using it since the page starts, make sure the var is initialised as [] and not as NULL.

Comment: projects: Project[] = []; // project.component.ts.... by console                                                                                                                       {…}
​
data: Array [ {…} ]
​
pageNumber: 0
​
totalOfElements: 1
​
totalPages: 1
​
<prototype>: Object { … }

Answer (score 1):

Like `Lucas` said to initialize as an empty array is a good idea

```
projects = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.pro.getAll().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.projects = response.data; // add .data here.
      },
      () => console.log('error')
    );
  }
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/features/project/project.component.ts(24,33): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Project[]'

Comment: Check out `(response: any)`, I think you are mistakenly saying that `getAll()` returns `Project[]` but it doesn't.